# Rebuilding a raid5 array from images

Tags: linux, raid5

I have an 8 disk *possibly* raid5 array that was part of a fried NAS, the whole thing uses pdc20265 promise chips and some kind of embedded system on a small ide board. No clue if the board is anything readable, possibly it is fried.

dmraid doesn't seem to work with images and mdadm doesn't seem to let you build arrays w/out metadata.

Anybody has a pointer on how to coerce the device mapper to assemble the array from the images so I can try to figure out what's inside?

The company that created the nas doesn't seem to exist anymore and the array is 10 years old. (and the friend asking for help doesn't remember much about the setup).

Comment: i had to do this a long time ago, it was painful, very painful.
i followed this guide http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~peterb/linux/raidextract/